# How to Make URLs clickable inside of UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview, hyperlink

I know how to use UIWebView and can invoke a WebView if it is associated with a specific button or UITableViewCell. What I am trying to achieve is to have a UITableViewCell with a chunk of text. That chunk of text might contain a URL. I want to make the URL into a clickable link and have that link open into a WebView.

My thought so far has been that I need to detect a link and insert it as a UIButton within the cell... but I don't know if that is the right way to go about this.

Any ideas or input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `TTLink` class in combination with `TTTableControlCell` of the excellent [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20/) project.